# Cannot use defroutes macro from compojure

Tags: clojure, macros, compojure

When running this code :

```
    (:use 'compojure.core)
    (keys (ns-publics 'compojure.core))


    (defroutes app-routes
      (GET "/" [] "Hello World")
      (route/resources "/")
      (route/not-found "Not Found"))
```

I got this message:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: defroutes in this context, compiling:(restful_clojure\routes.clj:5:1)
```

but when I run:

```
    (keys (ns-publics 'compojure.core))
```

it shows that macro is defined:

```
    (defroutes PUT POST routing routes make-route let-routes DELETE ANY let-request GET HEAD PATCH context OPTIONS)
```

Comment: Could you post the whole file and describe how you run your code? I just started REPL in terminal with compojure on classpath and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Clojure has methods [`require`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/require), [`import`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/import), [`refer`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/refer), and [`use`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/use). These are for working with different namespaces.

`:use` is a [Keyword](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Keyword.java), which can behave like a function (in your example it should return `nil`), but does not do what you want.

The confusion likely arises from the fact that **inside the [`ns` macro](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ns)**, you can 'embed' the behavior of these functions using the corresponding keywords.

For more reading on namespaces, see this [link](http://clojure.org/reference/namespaces).